# Bash - nested variable expansion inside command assignment

Tags: bash, assign, expansion

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm new to bash scripts and the syntactical process here is beyond me. I can't seem to find the right search terms to find what I need. This script is really just a stepping stone to my final version.

Invocation: ./myscript.sh testFile

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
awk='{print $9}' # do not expand $9
awk="'/$file/$awk'" # DO expand file argument
echo "$awk" # prints '/graphic/{print $9}' (as expected)
echo "ls -l | awk $awk" # prints ls -l | awk '/graphic/{print $9}' (as expected)
test="$(ls -l | awk $awk)" # error
echo "$test"
```

Output:

```
'/testFile/{print $9}'
ls -l | awk '/testFile/{print $9}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> ' <<< 
    missing }
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Even though I can copy and run the second echo'd line and it works successfully, the failure of the command leads me to believe this is not simple string concat but some crazier voodoo.

I've tried some other version as well like making a variable containing the whole command, but then I get even less expected output.

If I do *test="$($awk)"* I get

```
'/testFile/{print $9}'
ls -l | awk '/testFile/{print $9}'
ls: $9}': No such file or directory
ls: '/testFile/{print: No such file or directory
ls: awk: No such file or directory
ls: |: No such file or directory
```

If I do *test=$(awk)* I get

```
'/testFile/{print $9}'
ls -l | awk '/testFile/{print $9}'
usage: awk [-F fs] [-v var=value] [-f progfile | 'prog'] [file ...]
```

Since my Google queries basically only contain the words "bash command variable assignment", I can't get anything related to the nested variable expansion that I have here. I understand what it's doing based on the error, but I couldn't say why or how to fix it.

If someone could provide a fix as well as explain or point me to a resource explaining what's going on here, it would be greatly appreciated. Or maybe there's even another approach that would simplify the logic.

Thanks!

Comment: `set -x` and http://www.shellcheck.net are your friends.

Comment: Cool, set -x seems to reveal that escaped single quotes are being added... question is how to fix it...

Comment: Ok I have something that's working (test="$(ls -l | awk "$awk")") but it will take some more studying as far as how to avoid this mistake. It seems to be that string variables are not just defined by quotes but also are inherently wrapped by quotes when you use them later. So I don't directly have control over how my commands are quoted.

Comment: Storing commands (or even parts of commands) doesn't work very well because quotes in variables (as opposed to around them) don't work in any sane way. See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
test="$(ls -l | awk "$awk")" # error
```

`awk` requires the script to be a single argument. But when you expand a variable outside double quotes, the shell performs word splitting, so `$awk` is expanded into two arguments:

1. `'{print`
2. `$9}'`

The quotes keep the expansion as a single argument.

Also, take the single quotes out of

```
awk="'/$file/$awk'"
```

Single quotes are not processed after expanding a variable, so they'll be passed literally to `awk`. Putting double quotes around `$awk` achieves the result you were trying to get with these quotes.